# SharePoint Online - Access Denied - When creating a Page in a folder under Pages Library

Tags: publishing-page, wiki, online

I'm having an issue with creating a page in a folder under the Pages library.

Here is the structure:

- Publishing feature is enabled
- All the users have **read** permission on the site
  collection.
- There is a Pages library where unique permissions have been enforced.

Users have only read permission on the root of the folder '**Pages**', but sub folder has **contribute** access for example Marketing folder. The idea is that nobody should be allowed to create pages on the root of the '**Pages**' library but they can create pages in the specific folders.

I've tried the giving **contribute access** (and also full control) to **Master Page Gallery** but this didn't resolve the issue. I think this issue is related to access with */layout/CreatePage.aspx*.

What works:

- If I give user contribute access to pages library, but that defeats
  the purpose as we want to block users creating pages on the root or
  any other folder except their own dept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending quite a lot of time, I understand from Microsoft support that this model by designed.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/51144c18-bec7-427b-a22a-bda0573c5463/sharepoint-onilne-access-denied-when-creating-a-page-in-a-folder-under-pages-library?forum=sharepointgeneral

Therefore, one will have to give contribute permission to 'Pages' library.  I could restrict department to their respective folders, but they could still create pages on the root (Pages Library).