# SharePoint 2013 Issue sharing 'Folder' within Document Libraries

Tags: 2013, permissions, folder, access

I'm hoping there are others who have experienced an issue with Sharing folders on SharePoint 2013?

Using the **Share** functionality within a document library, I am able to invite users (to edit or read) on a folder who then receive the automated email containing a link to the folder where they then get the access denied page.

I can see these users are listed as having explicit access to the folder and when I send a direct link to the folder...still get

> access denied.

When the users select the option to Request Access from the above page, I can see in the list of requests that the request is for the library rather than the folder (even though the link they received was for the folder).

I have tried the same process at site/library/file level and it all works as expected - just not for folders.

Has anyone else had experience with this and able to advise what's happening? Thanks

Comment: Do you have publishing feature enabled on the site?

Comment: @SharePointer The publishing feature is turned on yes

Comment: Have a look at this.  I had a similar issue some time ago. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164446/sharepoint-online-access-denied-when-creating-a-page-in-a-folder-under-pages/169160#169160

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?